# E: Unable to locate package libsystemd-dev

Tags: 14.04, apt, dependencies

I am trying to install `libsystemd-dev` using `apt-get` on Ubuntu 14.04. While executing this, I get the following error:

```
 **Installing pre-install packages ....
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libsystemd-dev**
```

I have already tried using `apt-get update`, but no luck.

I searched for libsystemd-dev [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/), and it's available for [Wily distribution](http://packages.ubuntu.com/wily/libsystemd-dev), but I am using trusty. Is there a way to get a package installed from another distribution?

Comment: Related: [This post](http://askubuntu.com/q/697040/37165) attempted to resolve dependency by installing sub-dependencies which exist in trusty, but still failed. Perhaps last resort without upgrading is install via PPA, if any.

Comment: Which PPA should I add to be specific?

Comment: Apparently, there is no such PPA for 14.04. If you can't wait for upgrading to 16.04, a better solution might be to use sub-dependencies for package you are trying to install and propose to the developer of that package i.e. [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/fpco/stackage/issues/696). Even such PPA exists, it might break existing system.

Comment: There's no such package in Trusty but we may be able to work around that. What are you trying achieve with the `libsystemd-dev` packages? You don't need unless you want to compile something from source that depends on it.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this:

`sudo apt-file update` to download the package list.

```
sudo apt-file search libsystemd
```

After this you will get the list of packages:

`libsystemd-daemon-dev` and other packages like `libsystemd-login-dev` and `libsystemd-journal-dev`

Install these packages using `sudo apt-get install <package>`